# Why isn't all the java bytecode initially interpreted to machine code?

Tags: jvm, interpreter, java, bytecode

I read about [Just-in-time compilation (JIT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) and as I understood, there are two approaches for this – [Interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) and JIT, both of which interpreting the [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) at runtime.

Why not just preparatively interprete all the bytecode to machine code, and only then start to run the process with no more need for interpreter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: Because it takes time to precompile everything to machine code. And users don't want to wait on the application to start. Remember, the precompilation would have to make a lot of optimizations which takes time.

The server version of JVM is more aggressive in precompiling and optimizing code upfront because code on the server side tends to be executed more often and for a longer period of time before the process is shutdown.

However, a solution (for .Net) is an application called NGen which make the precompilation upfront such that it isn't needed after that point. You only have to run that once.

Not all VM's include an interpreter. For instance Chrome and CLR (.Net) always compiles to machine code before running. However, they have multiple levels of optimizations to reduce the startup time.

Answer (score 6):

Another reason for late JIT compiling has to do with optimization: At run-time the VM can detect more/other patterns it may optimize than the compiler could ever do at compile-time. JIT pre-compiling at startup will always have to be static, and the same could have been done by the compiler already, but through analysis of the *actual* run-time behaviour the VM may have more information on possible optimizations and may therefore produce better optimization results.

For example, the VM can detect that a single piece of code is actually run a million times at run-time and perform appropriate optimizations which the compiler may have no information about, not unlike the branch prediction that's done at runtime in modern CPUs.
More information can be found in the Wikipedia article on ["Adaptive optimization"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_optimization).

Comment: In addition, it can make assumptions about behavior and then recompile on the fly if those assumptions are later violated. This is important because otherwise you can't really inline virtual functions.

Comment: +1, but we also have profile-guided optimizations in compilers, so the same thing(ish) could be done at compile-time.

Comment: "Nothing beats the real thing." ;) - But the profile-guided optimizations go in the same direction. For reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile-guided_optimization

Answer (score 0):

I found [link](https://plumbr.eu/blog/java/do-you-get-just-in-time-compilation) showing how runtime recompilation can optimize performance and save extra CPU cycles.

- Inlining expansion: To decrease the cost of procedure calls.
- Removing redundant loads:  When 2 compiled code results in some duplicate code then it can be removed and further optimised by recompilation at run time.
- Copy propagation
- Eliminating dead code

Here is another [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15058/underst_jit.htm) for the same explanation given above.